# What would cause SVN to remove a file?

Tags: svn

I had a set of files one day, I did an SVN commit in a front end app called Cornerstone on the Mac. 2 days later (after a weekend) I found that one of the files I had was deleted. There's no record of a deletion transaction in the log and no information in the log as to what might have happened to the file.

Any ideas or information? I'm desparate to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Did the file disappear just from the working copy, from a certain commit, or both?

Comment: serverfault.com is more proper place

Comment: Does the log show that both files were committed?  That would be the next thing I check.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file showing in the repo browser?

Have you just deleted it locally? Maybe try updating the directory it's contained in again, the repository might still have a copy.